# Shiny User session ID in Body

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am wondering. Is there any approach to display session user id in body and then use it as variable in shiny/shinydashboard ? When my colleague is login to my app he could only see my id each time.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)


ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(column(4, wellPanel(
                      dateInput('date',
                                label = 'Date input: ',
                                value = Sys.Date()),
                      h5(tags$b("Request Owner")),
                      textOutput("user"))))
)



server <- function(input, output,session) {

  user_name <- function() {
    return(Sys.getenv()["USERNAME"][[1]])
    ### or return(Sys.getenv("USERNAME"))
  }

  #pobierz nazwe usera
  output$user <- user_name


}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible as it would be a major security issue for a website to access a local user's info. You may be able to get IP address info via session$clientData.

Comment: @Chabo Exposing request IP info in Shiny is still an open issue and has been for 5 years now. https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/141

Comment: @Chrisss well, forget that then.